# Fixing uv map of mesh

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I've got a mesh in blender that has a pretty bad uv issue. [image]

As you can see in the image, the uv seems to have shifted to the top while some parts of it kept dragging along the way. The mesh is stupidly high poly, so I tried to unsubdivide it, but that just breaks the uv even more, even parts that weren't broken before...

I'd just like to know if there's any way to salvage this ? I did try unwrapping and "pin to cursor" but to no avail.

I didn't make that mesh, nor did I make the blender file that contains it, so I'm shooting in the dark currently.

Thank you for any response and have a nice day!!

Comment: In UV editor mode and within the 3D view you can select faces and the relevant UVs will be selected in the editor, you can then scale and move them to fit the texture map. As the UVs are in panels you should also be able to see the seams in the model making it easier to select the right areas, you can then remap if needed. When doing 3D always save often in progressive files so you can revert back to a previous revision.

Comment: I was afraid that was the solution. Gonna take a long time to fix, thanks for the help!!